# How do rule-based systems deal with recursion?

Tags: recursion, rule-engine, finite-automata

I am just beginning to learn about rule-based systems, and am having trouble understanding how they can handle recursion.

Some quick background. I have studied a little programming language theory and so am pretty familiar with Context-Free Grammars and stuff like that. I have recently come across rule-based systems and am wondering how they may be related to automata and recursion.

> My question is: how do rule-based systems handle recursion? In particular, could a rule-based system be used for parsing nested parentheses? (Or parsing a CFG)?

I don't have a deep understanding of rule-based systems yet, but from what it *seems*, rules are never organized into a hierarchy or a network. Is this true, or is there a way to represent them as a hierarchy or network?

Without the ability to create a hierarchy of rules, it seems like the rule-system memory would have to keep track of the context manually, and that context would be used to test conditions. So like:

```
if parentConditionX and parentParentConditionY {
  perform some action
}
```

But then the problem is, how do you return to a "parent" rule (like a parent function context)? If rules can't be organized/executed hierarchically, it seems you can't do recursion? That's where I'm confused.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, from https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~nelson/courses/csc_173/grammars/cfg.html: "A context-free grammar (CFG) is a set of recursive rewriting rules (or productions) used to generate patterns of strings. " So any CFG-based parser is a system based on rules.  The lex and yacc utilities seem to be classifiable under the term "rule-based" from what I have read on Wikipedia.  Parsing indeed generates "parse trees" which do retain a hierarchical structure of rule application.  I am positive someone can answer this better than I can, though.